# How do I use ranges in g++ 10?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Here is my program

```
#include <concepts>
//#include <coroutine>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::vector<int> elements{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    
    for(auto current: elements | ranges::view::filter([](auto e){return e%2==0;})){
      std::cout<<current<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it with `g++ --std=c++20 main.cpp`, and I'm getting following error:

```
main.cpp:12:34: error: ‘ranges’ has not been declared
   12 |     for(auto current: elements | ranges::view::filter([](auto e){return e%2==0;})){
      |
```

g++ version is `10.3.0`

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean `std::ranges::views::filter`?

Comment: It looks like you're just missing a `std::` qualification. Either that, or you accidentally left out a `using` directive in your example.

Comment: @NathanPierson using std fixes the first error and than fails with `error: expected ‘auto’ or ‘decltype(auto)’ after ‘view’`

Comment: Did you also change `view` to `views`?

Comment: no, looks like I was using invalid example, views is actually in std::views and not std::ranges namespace

Answer (score 0):

The example I used was incorrect.
Code below will compile:

```
#include <concepts>
//#include <coroutine>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::vector<int> elements{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    
    for(auto current: elements | std::views::filter([](int e){return e%2==0;})){
      std::cout<<current<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```